# "passwordResetLink" link failed to generate in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I want to create a forgot password system in my application  (Asp.Net Core 2.2).  I generate a token successfully. but the problem is when I generate a `passwordResetLink`  it's null.

```
var passwordResetLink = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account",
                    new { email = model.Email, token = token }, Request.Scheme);
```

I don't understand that my `email` and `token` is not null but why `passwordResetLink`  is null?

here is my all code:-

```
 [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
                
                if (user != null)
                {
                    // Generate the reset password token
                    var token = await userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
                    
                    var passwordResetLink = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account",
                    new { email = model.Email, token = token }, Request.Scheme); //here is the main problem.why it's null?
                  
                     return View("ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
                }

                return View("ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
            }

            return View(model);
        }
```

Startup.cs file(ConfigureServices):-

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddTransient<IBraintreeService, BraintreeService>();
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
                //options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                // Make the session cookie essential
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4).AddDefaultTokenProviders()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }
```

Here is my output:-

[image]

Comment: `Url.Action()` will return null if it can't find a route matching the provided parameters. _Do_ you have an `AccountController` with a `ResetPassword` action method, accepting an `email` and `token` parameter?

Comment: @CodeCaster thanks for reply.i have AccountController and ResetPassword method. also i used ```Area``` in my project.

Comment: In which area is the AccountController?

Comment: @CodeCaster my area name is ```Display1```

Comment: Then use `new { email = model.Email, token = token , area = "Display1" }`.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks, I will try then I will get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

You should create two class like this:

```cs
public class ResetPasswordTokenProvider<TUser> : DataProtectorTokenProvider<TUser> where TUser : class
{
    public ResetPasswordTokenProvider(IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider,
            IOptions<ResetPasswordTokenProviderOptions> options)
            : base(dataProtectionProvider, options)
    {
    }
}
public class ResetPasswordTokenProviderOptions : DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions
{
    public ResetPasswordTokenProviderOptions()
    {
        Name = "ResetPasswordDataProtectorTokenProvider";
        TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
    }
}
```

And register created class to identity provider:

```cs
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(identityOptions =>
            {
                identityOptions.Tokens.ProviderMap.Add("ResetPassword",
                    new TokenProviderDescriptor(typeof(ResetPasswordTokenProvider<IdentityUser>)));
                identityOptions.Tokens.PasswordResetTokenProvider = "ResetPassword";
            })
            .AddTokenProvider<ResetPasswordTokenProvider<IdentityUser>>("ResetPassword")
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```